# Big O complexity when two functions f(n) [O(1)] and g(n) [O(n)] are multiplied together

Tags: big-o

f(n) and g(n) represent the running time of two different algorithms. f(n) has algorithm complexity O(1), and g(n) has algorithm complexity O(n). Can we claim f(n)*g(n) has complexity O(n)? Why/Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mathematical proof:

If we want to proof that f(n)*g(n) is O(n) we must show that exists `n0` and constant `c` such as :

```
f(n)*g(n) < c*n for every n>n0
```

We have as fact that f(n) is O(n) which means that there are c1,n1 :

```
f(n)<c1*n for every n>n1  (1)
```

and for g there are c2,n2:

```
g(n)<c2 for every n>n2    (2)
```

Now we have that, for every `n>max(n1,n2)` (max because we want both inequalities for f and for g to hold):

```
f(n)g(n)<c1*c2*n (by multiplying (1),(2))
```

so we proved that there is `c=c1*c2 and n0=max(n1,n2)`  such as the below inequality holds:

```
f(n)g(n)<c*n -> f(n)*g(n) is O(n) for every n>n0.
```

Answer (score 0):

O(n) is time complexity . When we multiply f(n) and g(n).The higher time complexity obtain so,algorithm complexity is O(n).

Comment: can you please prove? I need to prove it for this question. That is:

Comment: since f(n) is O(1), we know that there exists a real number n>n0 such that f(n)< C (where C is some constant); similarly for g(n) we know there exists a real number n>n0' such that g(n)<C'n. How do we prove that there exists another real number n>n0" such that f(n)*g(n) < C"n